# Subtraction of date and time from file contents containing dates line by line

Tags: java

```
while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
        {

          String line1=str;

          String line2=br.readLine();

            int datedifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(8,10))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(8,10));
            int yeardifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(11,15))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(11,15));
            int hourdifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(16,18))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(16,18));
            int minutedifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(19,21))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(19,21));
            int seconddifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(22,23))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(22,23));
            int lastthingdifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(24,28))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(24,28));
```

`System.out.println(hourdifference);}` After excuting this I am getting error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1" 

at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)  

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

at project.Subtract.main(Subtract.java:49)
```

Java Result: 1

Answer (score 0):

The `Integer.parseInt(String str)` method will fail if the string contains anything other than numbers. In your case, your substring starts with a white space, so to fix it you would need to use the [`.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method to remove any leading/trailing white spaces like so:

```
int datedifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(8,10).trim())-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(8,10).trim());
```

EDIT: As per your comment, you could do something like so:

```
int datedifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(8,10).trim())-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(8,10).trim());

int returnVal = Math.abs(dateDifference);    //This will return the absolute value of an integer, so -50 will yield 50, while 50 will still yield 50.
```

Comment: I edited it but still getting same errors like       "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string: ":5"

Comment: @MaduBiradar: You will need to post what you are actually reading. That is a similar error to the one you are posting.

Comment: @MaduBiradar: ":5" is not valid number

Comment: @MaduBiradar: I meant the data from the file. But if it is working then good for you :)

Comment: @all, what if i get negative values after subtraction ?? how can I make them positive values like doing  -50 to +50..

Comment: @npinti, I am new student to java and  I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: @MaduBiradar: No worries. That being said, I strongly recommend you search for your problems before posting them here. When you do so, you learn much more since you come across different people with different methods :).

Comment: @npinti, I Agree ,How nice way to guide me.. thank you so much.:)

Answer (score 0):

Use The [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library it can be helpful to calculate differences between Date and Time